# Issue with delineation using dem because of a DAM

Tags: qgis, raster, dem, hydrology

I have a high-resolution DEM which I use it delineate watershed.
I am getting the delineation like this

[image]

The main branch is not getting delineating till the source.
So I used a hillshade to check the issue.
[image]

A presence of a Dam is actually causing the issue and the values in the dem suddenly peaks due to it.
[image]

How do I fix this issue using Qgis?

Comment: Any chance of getting a pre-dam DEM?

Comment: The dam exists since 1985 as per Google earth historical imagery

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly common occurrence. You should be able to fix is quite easily by running the "Fill Sinks" tool in SAGA. There are several ones to chose from. It literally just lifts low points in your DEM to allow for smooth flow of water. The resultant DEM is "hydrologically correct"

Comment: Fill sinks creates issues in other parts of the dem. The dammed region and the low lying creates a difference of 18m elevation

Comment: Yeah so clip the filled dem to the area where you are having the issue. Merge the original and filled dem and then now you have a correction in the area for delineating watersheds. The filled/merged dem is only useful for delineation. Another solution is to simply remove the dam from the DEM. Just lower the cells.